# Using "on this day" VS "on that day"

Tags: past-tense

Is it correct to use "on this day" when talking about a day in the past or should it be "on that day"

Example: I took an exam a week before, and the results finally came out on this day

Answer (score 1):

The results came out **today**.

The results came out on **that day**. [which day is not specified]

**This day** is wrong here. Very old-fashioned, not used commonly. It can be used in ceremonial circumstances or historical ones.

"This day is important for him." That's the right way to use it. It can also be said as "Today is important for him."

Answer (score 1):

We use 'this day' to talk about 'today' (old-fashioned) or else an event that happened on the same date in the past. On this day in AD 301 San Marino, one of the smallest nations in the world, was founded, and in 1939, Britain declared war on Germany after the invasion of Poland. "This day" today means "September 3rd". We use 'that day' to refer to any other day, in the past or future, that has been mentioned or referred to already.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you have old-fashioned right after the word today.

Comment: Yes. I was saying that it is old fashioned to use "this day" to mean "today".